# DocuSign configuration error in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi, dynamics-365

I need your help in order to install DocuSign in my Dynamics 365, please.
I am trying to install and configure a DocuSign trial in my Dynamics 365 Demo and I am facing a lot of errors and I can’t finish it.

1. First of all, I created a new Trial in [Docusign Platform](https://appdemo.docusign.com/home)

   [image: DocuSign loggin]
2. After that, I installed the DocuSign application in my Tenant:

   [image: Tenant]
3. After all of this, I logged in Dynamics 365 using Admin user and I can see the following strange processes in our Dynamics. Could you tell us what these processes are referring to?

   [image: Process]

---

On the other hand, I am trying to configure in DocuSign Admin Section > Settings and I face the following error when I try to enable the “Save completed documents to SharePoint” option:

- I select the second option:

[image]

- And the following error is facing: [this is the url](https://partner.docusign.net/partners/msdynamics/error?message=System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException+(0x80004005)%3a+A+potentially+dangerous+Request.QueryString+value+was+detected+from+the+client+(message%3d%26quot%3b...+The+view+%26amp%3b%2339%3bsharepoint%26amp%3b%2339%3b...%26quot%3b).%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String+value%2c+String+collectionKey%2c+RequestValidationSource+requestCollection)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String+key)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpValueCollection.GetValues(String+name)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider.ValueProviderResultPlaceholder.GetResultFromCollection(String+key%2c+NameValueCollection+collection%2c+CultureInfo+culture)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider.GetValue(String+key%2c+Boolean+skipValidation)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderCollection.GetValue(String+key%2c+Boolean+skipValidation)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext+controllerContext%2c+ModelBindingContext+bindingContext)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext+controllerContext%2c+ParameterDescriptor+parameterDescriptor)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext+controllerContext%2c+ActionDescriptor+actionDescriptor)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.%26lt%3b%26gt%3bc__DisplayClass21.%26lt%3bBeginInvokeAction%26gt%3bb__19(AsyncCallback+asyncCallback%2c+Object+asyncState)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase%601.Begin(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state%2c+Int32+timeout)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext+controllerContext%2c+String+actionName%2c+AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Controller.%26lt%3bBeginExecuteCore%26gt%3bb__1c(AsyncCallback+asyncCallback%2c+Object+asyncState%2c+ExecuteCoreState+innerState)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid%601.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+callbackState)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase%601.Begin(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state%2c+Int32+timeout)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase%601.Begin(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state%2c+Int32+timeout)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext+requestContext%2c+AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.%26lt%3bBeginProcessRequest%26gt%3bb__4(AsyncCallback+asyncCallback%2c+Object+asyncState%2c+ProcessRequestState+innerState)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid%601.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+callbackState)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase%601.Begin(AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state%2c+Int32+timeout)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase+httpContext%2c+AsyncCallback+callback%2c+Object+state)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep+step)%0d%0a+++at+System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep+step%2c+Boolean%26amp%3b+completedSynchronously)). Embedded in the url is a stack trace which includes the message:

  > A potentially dangeraus Request.QueryString value was detected from the Client

[image]

I can’t also enable entities:

[image]

Please, could you help me?

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign support. Stack Overflow is a forum for programming questions and you're unlikely to get help with this issue here.

Comment: Hello Kim, the reason to contact Stack Overflow is because DocuSign Support advised me that. Sorry, i will contact DocuSign support againl